# Windows Mobile Button not filling the edges

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone

I'm new to Window Mobile App Development and now I've to create the button, I have created it successfully, but the problem is it doesn't fill the edges of the button with the image i set to it.

[image]

I have set the border width and padding everything to 0 but still the issue exists and I have even checked in on the windows simulator 
[image]

This is how it looks. The button should fill the image? How it can be achieved?

Here is the code:

```
  <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="218" Margin="96,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,0.514" Source="/Assets/Images/qima_logo.png"/>
            <TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="46,301,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="3" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" InputScope="EmailUserName" AcceptsReturn="True" />
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="46,373,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366" BorderBrush="DarkGray" InputScope="Password"/>
            <Button Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,450,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366" Height="88">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/btn_bg.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Organization List" Margin="0,649,0,0" Width="455" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/organizations_list_btn.png" AlignmentX="Left"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Membership List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,580,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Foreground="White">
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/members_list_btn.png"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/members_list_btn.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" Margin="46,533,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Source="/Assets/Images/members_list_btn.png" Stretch="Fill">
                <Image.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/members_list_btn.png"/>
                </Image.OpacityMask>
            </Image>

        </Grid>
```

Comment: Please add the xaml code for this layout. Possibly a line, margin or padding setting.

Comment: I have added the code to my question